# How to use TigerGraph GSQL to associate data from one Vertex to another Vertex?

Tags: clone, graph-databases, vertex-attributes, tigergraph, gsql

I am a beginner and trying to make several Vertex shown on the TigerGraph Insights Map Widget.

The Map widget displays vertex attributes as latitude and longitude, and I have shown the Location Vertex on the Map Widget successfully.

But the other Vertex cannot be shown on Map Widget due to no latitude and longitude data.

I have large CSV file of latitude and longitude for the “Location Vertex” and want to use GSQL to traverse these geolocation attributes to another Vertex, finally these Vertexes could be displayed on the map widget.

For example, my Vertex relations are shown in the pic.

[Vertex & Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3bd7.png)

I want to find out whether there is a way to display the result of a GSQL that we would create in order to query the graph and associate dynamically the longitude and latitude data from a location to the corresponding action Vertex.

How can I use GSQL to associate these geolocation attributes from “Location Vertex” to “Action Vertex”?

Answer (score 0):

When using TigerGraph Insights you can use "actions". In the map widget, it's called "map actions" which can pass parameters from one widget to another. The blog below covers some of the parameter-passing functionality.

Map Widget:
https://docs.tigergraph.com/insights/current/widgets/map-widget

Create Links Between Pages:
https://www.tigergraph.com/blog/build-your-first-app-with-tigergraph-insights/

Widget Actions:
https://docs.tigergraph.com/insights/current/widgets/actions